# Whose belief is that the bible is

Tags: meaning-in-context

> His[Martin Luther] theology challenged the authority of the Pope **by teaching** that the Bible is the only source of divinely revealed knowledge from God.

Whose belief is it that the bible is the only source of divinely revealed knowledge from God? Is that the Pope's belief or Martin Luther's?

Comment: Was that sentence written in isolation? Even if that sentence is unclear to you, its meaning  should probably become clear by the meaning of surrounding sentences.

Answer (score 2):

Pattern:

Who - did what - in what way:

> His theology (=subject) 
> challenged (=predicate) 
> the authority of the Pope(=object: whom?)
>  by teaching that ... (= through the means)

=> It's Luther's belief.

(perhaps a native speaker could fill in the correct terms...)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified structure of the sentence:

> [A] challenged [B] by teaching [C].
>
> - A = Martin Luther's theology
> - B = the authority of the Pope
> - C = that the Bible is the only source of divinely revealed knowledge from God

Hopefully that makes it easier for you to see that it is [A] which teaches [C].

#### How the sentence would look if 'the B is the OS of DRK from G' was the Pope's belief instead of Luther’s belief

If it was the pope who believed that the Bible is the only source of divinely revealed knowledge from God, the sentence would look like this, instead:

> [A] challenged [B]'s belief that [C].
>
> - A = Martin Luther's theology
> - B = the Pope
> - C = that the Bible is the only source of divinely revealed knowledge from God
>
> Martin Luther's theology challenged the Pope's belief that the Bible is the only source of divinely revealed knowledge from God.

I hope that contrasting these two simplified structures will help you understand your sentence better.

Answer (score -1):

When you get confused, remove heavy words and come up with your own example putting simple words. Let's do that...

> "**My theory** challenged the authorities of the company by *teaching* that **the agile methodology** is the only way of getting projects done on time."

Here, who is being taught? The authority. Fine, what is being taught to them? The agile methodology. They learned about 'agile methodology' -through your theory? This means your theory must contain agile methodology that they learned? So, who believed in agile methodology first?

**YOU!**

Now change the actors. Luther takes places of yours! So, it's Luther's belief. :)

Comment: The sentence does not specify who is being taught. All that it says about authorities is that authorities were challenged by the theory.

Comment: Luther's theology "*challenged*" [the authoritiy of the pope], (which is a theological concept,) not "the authorities". You'd also need a "teaching *them*" in the original sentence for your answer to be correct.